# Почему не работают мягкие переходы страниц (barba)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax, gsap

Я подключил barba js(второй версии) и gsap через cdn:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

инициализировал барбу (JS):

```js
barba.init({
  transitions: [{
    name: 'legacy-example',
    leave: function(data) {
      var done = this.async();
      TweenMax.to(data.current.container, 1, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: done
      });
    },
    enter: function(data) {
      var done = this.async();
      TweenMax.to(data.next.container, 1, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: done
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

**НО страница перезагружается и ничего не работает**
**В консоли ничего не пишет**
**Что делать?**